# Should I use Reflection Cubemaps in Eevee (to achieve realistic lighting)?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, lighting, photorealism

**Should I use Reflection Cubemaps in Eevee?** I've seen a lot of tutorials about achieving realistic lighting in Eevee using Reflection Cubemaps and Irradiance Volumes. However, in the Blender manual it says: *"Screen Space Reflections are much more precise than reflection cubemaps. If enabled, they have priority and cubemaps are used as a fall back if a ray misses."* So, from my understanding, enabling Screen Space Reflections in the render settings gives more realistic reflections, and therefore Reflection Cubemaps are not necessary? Correct? Or is it best to use both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: use both! Eevee will mainly use Screen Space Reflections, but will also use Reflection Cubemaps as a secondary source (backup) for reflections where Screen Space Reflections fails. Using both gives the most accurate results.

Comment: If you were using cycles, don't you need all this?